# Several counts with dummy column by rows

Tags: sql-server-2008, count

Maybe its just very simple I want to have several counts based on different where clause and get the result in two columns one column with dummy entry the other with the count for each where clause. Better I show it:
My statement works fine in MSSQL 2008 but the output needs to be formated:

```sql
SELECT (    
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        from [Tasks].[dbo].[Lifecycle] 
        where oldwsid like '%L%' and Quarter = 'Q1'
   ) as 'Total Laptops',
   (    
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        from [Tasks].[dbo].[Lifecycle] 
        where oldwsid like '%W%' and Quarter = 'Q1'
   ) as 'Total Desktops'
```

The result is: (1 row with two columns)

```
Total Laptops | Total Desktops  
100             20
```

but I would like to have it this way:(2 rows with 2 columns)

```
Total Laptops    100   
Total Desktops   20
```

Like that I could easy overtake it. Is there a way with this dummy columns?

Thanks a lot for any help

Answer (score 0):

UNION may solve your problem

```
SELECT (    
    SELECT 'Total Laptops' Device,COUNT(*)  DeviceCount
    from [Tasks].[dbo].[Lifecycle] 
    where oldwsid like '%L%' and Quarter = 'Q1' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Total Desktops' Device,COUNT(*) DeviceCount
    from [Tasks].[dbo].[Lifecycle] 
    where oldwsid like '%W%' and Quarter = 'Q1'      

) as A
```